# Is it a good way to use PropertyChangeListener interface?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, propertychangelistener, propertychangesupport

I have a doubt related to the deep meaning and use of the **fireIndexedPropertyChange()** method that  fire an event that will be intercepted and handled by a **propertyChange()** listener that I declare in another class.

For example, in a class that implement a login GUI (that show a login form) with a JButton I have this method that is performed when the user clik on my button:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Button cliccked");

    Main listener = new Main();                         // I intantiate a new Main object to have the PropertyChangeListener
    this.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);           // I add the PropertyChange Listener to this LoginFrame object

    /* I fire a PropertyChange: the event start and will be handled by the propper propertyChange() method definied in the
     * listener class: 
     * 
     * @param "loginButtonClicked" 
     * */
    firePropertyChange("loginResult", false, loginResult);   


}
```

So, when the not yet logged user click on my button this method is performed and it fire a new **PropertyChange** event.

My **PropertyChange** event take itself the following informations:

1. The **propertyName** that is a name of a property that could be changed (in my example is named **loginResult** because I have a boolean variable named **loginResult** and the value is true if the user can log in when clikc the button, false otherwise
2. An **old value** is the old value of the property that could be changed (in my example is false because if the user see the login windows it means that it is not logged in and the **loginResul=false**
3. The **new value**: in this case it is the content of the **loginResult** variable (true if the user is being logged in the system)

So this **PropertyChange** event will be intercepted by my **propertyChange()** method (declared in a listener class) that handle it based on these parameters: for example in the following way:

** if the propertyName is loginResult and if the new value is true then don't display again the login window but display the main application window**

Is it my reasoning correct and it could be a good way to use the **PropertyChangeListener** interface?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Creating a new Main and adding a new listener each time a button is clicked looks completely wrong, but I'm not sure what you want to do. Do you want to display the main frame if the login is successful?

Comment: As a general comment so that we converge on a common vocabulary, events in java are not said to be intercepted; this implies that they go somewhere else after the listener gets them. You can use "received" or "handled". I don't know if this is the right term in other languages but i have never heard it in java

Comment: @JBNizet yes, I want to display the main frame if the login is successful. You are completly right: it is very stupid thing create a new Main object every time that the user click on the button...so now I create it once time as a static variable without the LoginFrame constructor...so I think that it is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like that and it will work. But I think your question is more about semantics rather than just whether it works. The package of that interface is `java.beans` which puts it in a context of beans. If you are using it in a beans context, i.e. your event publisher is a bean then I think the "deep meaning" of the interface agrees with your use. The javadoc says

> A "PropertyChange" event gets fired whenever a bean changes a "bound" property.

If you don't think it goes well with beans then create your own

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use events to implement your use-case. You're overengineering simple things. The code should simply look like the following:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String login = loginTextField.getText();
    char[] password = passwordField.getPassword();
    boolean loginSuccessful = authenticationService.authenticate(login, password);
    if (loginSuccessful) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);
    }
    else {
        displayErrorMessage("Login failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: this is right but I think that I can't do this because: 1) Main is not a class that implements a Swing GUI but is also a class where there is declared and created my GUI objects and the listener. So I have to use events to: execute a listener method into the Main class and this method have to setVisible(false) on the LoginFrame object and setVisible(true) on my main GUI object (that is created into the Main class)

Comment: No, there's no reason to do that. If Main is not a JFrame, but has a method to show a JFrame, then call this method: `Main main = new Main(); main.createAndDisplayFrame();`

Comment: It's an old post, but people probably still read it so to be clear: it's the worst approach you can make. If authentication is time-consuming (and as it is because it is networking) then your window will hang there. You should never make anything but GUI-stuff in GUI-thread. Use PropertyChangeListener.

Comment: @Chlorek Using a PropertyChangeListener won't magically execute the authentication service call in a separate thread. **If** the authentication is too long to be handled in the UI thread, then yes, of course it's a good idea to do it in a separate thread. But PropertyChangeListener has nothing to do with that. You'd need a SwingWorker.

Comment: Well PropertyChangeListener does not "magically" execute your net-code in another thread, but if you have another thread with netcode then it can safely call property change and GUI-thread will get notified.

Comment: No. The listener would be invoked synchronously, in the same "net" thread, and you would then create a new Swing frame in a thread other then the event dispatch thread, which violates the swing threading rules.

Comment: Ok so I looked into my code, and I find why it worked fine - I had firePropertyChange() wrapped to be run on EDT. I thought I had this functionality built-in, my bad then. Anyway one can use that approach or worker (I have entire network protocol based on propertychange).